# How to create a release for Github using the egit-github library?

Tags: java, github

Using this library, https://github.com/eclipse/egit-github, what do I have to do to have it create a new release through Java code.

Comment: What does "release" entail in your use case? What have you already done/tried, what are you struggling with?

Comment: I guess, egit-github isn't meant to create release. It is used to look back the previous code.

Comment: You can refer to [jgit-cookbook](https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook). I don't think they provide support to create a release.
**Sidenote:** Egit is built using Jgit.